# Can humanity discover Monsters world?

Tags: aliens, alternate-worlds, teleportation

Recent favorite fairy tale of my family is Pixar's classic: [Monsters Inc.](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0198781/) After watching it for millionth time, I have a question:

**Would we be able to discover that there is "Monsters world"?**

For those two, who did not see the fairy tale there are few details:

- ghosts, yettis, vampires and all other mythical creatures exist and they are members of Monster world
- Monster world is a planet far far away, the creatures are real, but have no magical powers. Usual rules of physics apply for them
- Monsters see us the same "scary" as we are scared of the Monsters
- Monsters come to visit our bedrooms to scare us. Produced scream then powers the Monsters' houses.
- The monsters visit us by creating a portal mapped to any door to our planet (whatever you would call a door can be used as gateway to Monster world)
- Both function of the portal and why scream produces power are hand-waved. Just assume "it works perfectly"
- Monsters aim to produce scream only from children, aged 3-7 years (reasons why are out of scope, again, just please accept this as a fact)
- Monsters follow [six sigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Sigma) principle. From each 1 000 000 scared children, there are 3 mishaps.
- Monsters scare 1 000 000 human children in a month. The scaring is randomly distributed all around the Earth
- Scaring happens "now" (Earth, current day and tech)

So, given that only 3 children in a month (from whole Earth) are in situation where humanity could potentially discover the Monster world, are we able to get the clues? Or are the 3 kids just candidates for local tabloid news?

Comment: So, what you are asking is: are we going to detect it through the mishaps? And are we subsequently able to pass through the doors?

Comment: Exactly: Is the small number of mishaps (especially when randomly separated all over the Earth) enough for us to realise something weird is going on? Or is it going end only in tabloids?

Comment: @Burki edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: You can improve the success rate by GPS tagging every toddler, one is bound to wander into the monster world and do remember to include return address on the tag!

Comment: @user6760 I can, but before that, I actually have to believe that ghosts and nightmares of my children are actually real

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Sure

With 1Mn scares a month, we have a very significant level of interaction.  In the movie, there was never any demonstrated capability to avoid recording equipment.  I therefore suggest it would not long before Monsters are recorded in significant enough quantities that authorities would take the events seriously.

The Monsters dependance upon screams for energy would make it difficult for them to use effective avoidance tactics.

Once discovered the various Militaries(and others) in the world would spend considerable effort to capture, analyse and reverse engineer both the Monsters and their teleportation technology.

Comment: Currently video surveillance in children's rooms is not that commonplace. If this becomes more commonplace, i could imagine the Monsters adapt. But yes, you have a point there.

Comment: @Burki I agree it's not commonplace, but then neither is 1Mn intrusions a month!

Comment: "The monsters visit us by creating a portal mapped to any door to our planet"  There is ~7.3 Billion people on this planet, I don't have numbers, but I'm assuming a decent chunk of that falls in the age range from 3-7, and there has to be a lot of doors spread through the entire planet also! One million a month across the entire planet for that age range that has a door, wouldn't be that concerning based off 3 children's stories that are similar, and about scary monsters at night, and I'm sure 3 not close locations at all.

Comment: @Timmy is that a comment for the question or a new answer?

Comment: @NPSF3000 No, just a comment for intrusions being a reason to put cameras in children's room to watch all night. Just an idea why cameras might be tricky to justify.  Unless it's like one of those teddy cameras people use to watch babysitters. That might be reasonable!

Comment: @Timmy let's say 1% of 1% of parents put good quality recording equipment in their child's room (illness, paranoia, tracking, security) that'd be 100 cases a month.  You only need 1 good record for people to take it seriously.  In reality I suspect it'd be tens of thousands of cases a month (hundred thousand plus a year).  None of this is caused by monsters (though a repeatedly visited child might cause the parents to use a camera to 'prove' to her nothing is wrong...), rather society at large happening to stumble upon them.